# Why doesn't SQL Developer display package code?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When selecting a package from the connections tree, SQL Developer does not display the package content but instead only shows an empty editor window with the single line "create or replace".
This applies to package specification and body as well as functions and procedures.
The selected connection/user is the owner of the objects.

[screenshot connections tree/editor window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGxbu.png)

The database in question is a copy of the production system; on production packages are displayed normally.
SQL Developer version is Version 18.1.0.095

Comment: The only way I can see that is if I have a package body with no specification. But then the body is shown with a red cross in the tree. (Seems to behave the same in 18.1 and the current 19.1, but you could try upgrading.) Can you look at the SQL actually being used via View->Log and then the Statements tab? What do you see if you query the data dictionary manually (e.g. `user_source` or `all_source` for that package name; and `user_objects` - do you see both `PACKAGE` and `PACKAGE BODY`, and what statuses do they have?

Comment: `user_source` shows all lines, both objects are visible and valid in `user_objects`.
This affects all source objects (packages, etc) in a working application.

Comment: What do you see if you manually run the same query SQL Developer uses internally (against `all_source` or `dba_source` depending on your privileges) as the same user you're connected as, and with the same bind values? If you can see the spec manually, and SQL developer can't, then it might be something to raise an SR about, or at least ask on the forum. If you can't query it manually either then it's (probably) not the client's fault, but might also need an SR to figure out what's happening. (I wondered about VPD but such a specific restriction seems unlikely. Unless it was a bad experiment.)

Comment: I have tested the behaviour on a collegue's PC and everything works fine there (using the same DB user and everything), so there is definitely something wrong with my software setup, not the database. Which is strange because I can access all other databases just fine.
I will re-install or upgrade SQL Developer and report back afterwards.
Thanks for your support so far!